# Virtualbox Ubuntu Guest - IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection - sqlDeveloper

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, oracle-sqldeveloper

Im using VirtualBox (host os WIN10 - guest os Ubuntu). My problem i that im unable to connect to oracle's database through sqldeveloper getting that error "IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection".

Facts: 
I have sql-developer both in windows and ubuntu. I can connect in windows to the databse where as in ubuntu i get that error.
To connect to the database on windows in need to establish connection to a private vpn. Which i do and everything is ok. The fun part is that i have access to that vpn because i can connect to a server in thath vpn using ssh. At last in the VM im using one adapter using NAT.

So i don't know why but with sqlDeveloper from ubuntu i cannot connect to the DB. 
Any help would be much appreciated

Update: Sometimes when i close and reopen my pc and launch my guest os (after i connect to the vpn) it can connect to the database !!! I don't know why but there must be an explanation to all this.

Comment: You can ping the machine from your VM?

Comment: ping what, i didn't understand you

Comment: Can you ping the DB box from your client...if not, you won't be able to connect to the database

Comment: yes i can. Also another thing is that SOMETIMES i have connection to my database from my guest os. I don't finf anything different that i do. I think it has to do with the VPN. I try every time to open it before i launch my guest os (Ubuntu).